# light node can perform any operation what fast and full sync mode do, exception getTransationreceipt?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, light-clients

I need to send ethereum between wallets or interact with a token on the ethereum network can a light node has a constraint to do that,it can not perform any task as a full or fast sync mode node, I read that getTransationreceipt a light node can not work because it is part of the block, there are some others transactions that does not support ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A light node should be able to perform any operation like a regular nodes, but it relies on full nodes to complete them.

If for some reason full nodes do not answer, or do not answer on time the operation will fail.

Unfortunately there aren't many full nodes answering, so more complex operations might fail.

Comment: ok, thanks @Ismael for the response, I want to use light nodes for my app, its better create one full node and then create as many light nodes I need, but with light nodes add only the full node as a trustedPeer in order to achive stability for any request from light nodes?

Comment: @andrew007 If you have a full node I don't see the need for light nodes. I'd start with infura or a light node, and move to a full node if needed.

Comment: ok, thanks for the response, the light nodes is to be attach to the full node just in case the full node don't response for a lot of request the light nodes will look for another one in the public network to resolve the request, I don't want to depend on a third party, thanks, it's for stability and scalability. thanks what do yo think ?

Comment: @andrew007 I don't see the need of light nodes if you already have a full node. I'll add some caching to the full node, perhaps some authentication or some redundancy. If you do not want to depend on third parties light nodes doesn't look like a good options.

Comment: thanks for the response, then only a full node will be able to perform and response a big amount of requests only adding a good amount of cache?

Comment: @andrew007 It depends on how many transaction and how many clients it is serving. If your intention is to run your own blockchain I'll recommend more than one node, at least 3, to have good redundancy.